# Remove leading zeros from a Buffer in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

Here's a 32-byte Buffer:

```
<Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 9a>
```

What is the best way to remove all leading zeros?

Expected output is:

```
<Buffer 02 9a>
```

---

My current approach:

```
function removePaddingLeft(value) {
  let pos
  let i = 0
  while (true) {
    if (value[i] !== 0) break
    pos = i++
  }
  return value.slice(pos + 1)
}
```

Comment: Put proper explanation of your problem and show your work in detail...

Comment: @Ivar NodeJS Buffer, https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

Comment: @YashParekh  What details do you need? The problem seems quite straightforward. Naive way would be to traverse buffer from the first byte and remove it if it's `00`. I am asking for the best way to do so.

Comment: @YashParekh If you **really** want to see my attempt, it's included in the question now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Same idea, but shorter:

```
function trimStart (d) {
  var i = 0
  while (!d[i] && (i < d.length))
    i++
  return d.slice(i)
}

trimStart(Buffer.from('000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000029a', 'hex'))
// returns <Buffer 02 9a>
```